# Fstreams C++ has extra spaces on writing

Tags: c++

I figured some stuff out, but I suck at fstreams, and this is just killing me, for BREED + DESC, they have a space between them and name, but when I remove them completely then I get no spaces and it works again. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


const int NAME_SIZE = 100;
const int BREED_SIZE = 100;
const int DESC_SIZE = 250;
const int REASON_SIZE = 250;

//creating the struct
struct animal
{
//members
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char breed[BREED_SIZE];
    char desc[DESC_SIZE];
    char reason[REASON_SIZE];
    float age;
    float weight;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    float length;
};

class petAdoption
{
    public:
        petAdoption();
        void enroll(animal newAnimal[], int & count);
        void read(animal newAnimal[], int & count);
        //void display(animal & newAnimal);
        //void adopt(animal & newAnimal); 
    private:


};
petAdoption::petAdoption()
{

}

int main()
{
int count = 0;
animal * newAnimal = new animal[count];
petAdoption adopt;
adopt.read(newAnimal, count);
adopt.enroll(newAnimal, count);
delete[] newAnimal;
}


void petAdoption::read(animal newAnimal[], int & count)
{
    int pets = 0;
    ifstream read;
    read.open("pets.txt");
    if(!read)
    {
        cout << "Checking... File doesn't exist!" <<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        while(!read.eof())
        {
        read.getline(newAnimal[pets].name, NAME_SIZE, '\n');
        read.ignore(100, '\n');
        ++pets;
        }
    count = pets + 1;
    }
    read.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < pets; ++i){
        read.open(newAnimal[i].name);
            if( !read)
            {
                cout << "Checking... File doesn't exist!" <<endl;
            }
        else{
            while(!read.eof())
            {
                read.getline(newAnimal[i].name, NAME_SIZE, '\n');
                read.getline(newAnimal[i].breed, BREED_SIZE, '\n');
                read.getline(newAnimal[i].desc, DESC_SIZE, '\n');
                read.getline(newAnimal[i].reason, REASON_SIZE, '\n');
                read.ignore(100, '\n');
                read >> newAnimal[i].age;
                read >> newAnimal[i].weight;
                read >> newAnimal[i].day;
                read >> newAnimal[i].month;
                read >> newAnimal[i].year;
                read >> newAnimal[i].length;
                read.ignore(100, '\n');
            }
        }
        read.close();
    }
}


/*
ENROLL FUNCTION
*/

void petAdoption::enroll(animal newAnimal[], int & count)
{
//making a write variable
    ofstream write;

//stores the name into the struct member
    cout << "Please enter a name: ";
    cin.get(newAnimal[count].name, NAME_SIZE, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a breed: ";
    cin.get(newAnimal[count].breed, BREED_SIZE, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a desc: ";
    cin.get(newAnimal[count].desc, DESC_SIZE, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a reason (EG: eats people): ";
    cin.get(newAnimal[count].reason, REASON_SIZE, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter an age (EG: 5): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].age;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a weight (in LBS): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].weight;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a day (EG: 2): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].day;
    cout << "Please enter a month (EG: 11): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].month;
    cout << "Please enter a year (EG: 2002): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].year;
    cout << "How long has the pet been in a shelter? (in months): ";
    cin >> newAnimal[count].length;


//error
    if(!write)
    {
        cout << "Invalid File" << endl;
    }
    else{
        write.open(newAnimal[count].name, ios::app);    
        write << newAnimal[count].name << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].breed << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].desc << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].reason << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].age << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].weight << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].day << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].month << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].year << '\n'
        << newAnimal[count].length << '\n';
        write.close();
    }
    if(!write) 
    {
        cout << "Invalid File";
    }
    else {
        write.open("pets.txt", ios::app);
        write << newAnimal[count].name << '\n';
        write.close();  
    }               
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char` arrays and not `std::string`?

Comment: \*yawn\* `while(!read.eof())` is wrong. What resource is teaching people this?

Comment: Can you mention clearly, what is the issue?

Comment: I want to find the instructors that teach `while (!file.eof())` and stone them to death. That aside, can you post some *sample **data*** ? Nothing huge, please.

Comment: @cppcoder the issue is when i put in all the data, when it saves the file, its like  NAME (NEWLINE) (NEWLINE) breed etc.

Comment: You can't do `if (!write)` _before_ you open the file!

Answer (score 1):

As people mention (in response to an earlier version of this question already) you shall not use `eof()` to control your loop . Furthermore you shall test that you successfully received your input after you [attempted] to read it.

The problem with extra newlines at the end if a line is due to your use of `get()` rather than `getline()`: the former retains the stop character while the latter does not. You should als consider using `std::string` together with `std::getline()`: it reads arbitrary length strings.

Comment: I gotta use char arrays. Also when I use getline it has the same problem. so I thought I'd try get.

Comment: No, you don't gotta use char arrays.

Comment: Two things: 1. Since you keep appending to a file, make sure the file initially empty and you are not trying to debug a problem resolved since you first wrote it. 2. Create a **small** example showing the problem. That is, copy your code and remove everything until only code showing the problem is lthere. I guess it shouldn't be more than 20 lines in your case. ... and `get()` and `getline()` certainly behave different in the way I stated.

Comment: I think my problem is in the enroll function, but honestly I've been trying to fix it for 3 hours. I suck xD. After awhile, it seems to just freeze on my cmd in linux, O.o

Comment: The prime aporoach to locating priblems is isolating them! Your source is to long for me to see where the problem is. If you'd reduce it to just a few lines, creating a program not meeting the original objective but also having the probkem, it tends to be a lot simpler to soit the problem. BTW, I got an error "503 service not available" on your picture.

Comment: The picture looks fine! I'll rewrite a simplified version of it and test it!